# How to turn complex sql into linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

For some time, I've been trying to transform this SQL into linq:

```sql
SELECT 
    Name
FROM
    Director d
JOIN 
    Movie m ON d.Id = m.DirectorId
JOIN 
    MovieActor ma ON m.Id = ma.MovieId
WHERE 
    ReleaseDate <= '2005-12-31'
    AND Rating >= 9
GROUP BY 
    Name
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ma.ActorId) BETWEEN 3 AND 7 
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN m.DurationMinutes >= 60 THEN m.DurationMinutes END) >= 2
;
```

Here 100% working part, which quite simple.

```cs
var query4 = (from d in directors
              join m in movies on d.Id equals m.DirectorId
              join ma in movieActors on m.Id equals ma.MovieId
              where m.ReleaseDate <= Convert.ToDateTime("2015-12-31")
              where m.Rating >= 9

              );
```

Mostly I'm struggling with these issues:

1. Referring to `d, m, ma` as single table instead of 3 connected somehow, because when I'm trying `group d by ... into g` I'm losing the other two tables.
2. I can't understand how count one parameter (to do condition check) without losing others.

Also `HAVING` syntax in linq is not obvious.

---

**Edit:**
I'm using LINQ to Objects provider, and here some:
Classes by initilization, which are bassiclly field containers

```cs
public Director(int _Id, string _Name)
public Movie(int _Id, string _Name, int _DurationMinutes, DateTime _ReleaseDate, int _DirectorId, int _Rating)
public Actor(int _Id, string _Name, int _Age)
public MovieActor(int _MovieId, int _ActorId)
```

And data I'm using for testing (gathering lists from these arrays)

```cs
var directorArr = new (int, string)[] { (1, "Bebopvsky"), (2, "Tarrantino"), (3, "CubeRick") };
            var actorArr = new (int, string, int)[] 
            {   (1, "Dat Maan",75), (2, "That Man", 28),
                (3, "Dat Women", 32), (4, "That Women", 22),
                (5, "Already Women", 12) };
            var moviesArr = new (int, string, int, DateTime, int, int)[] 
            {   (1, "Platform for soul", 121, Convert.ToDateTime("2018-12-31"), 2, 9),
                (2, "Full-featured access management", 42, Convert.ToDateTime("2019-01-01"), 3, 7),
                (3, "Robust LDAP server for Java", 13, Convert.ToDateTime("2005-05-25"), 3, 4),
                (4, "Man of Rain", 114, Convert.ToDateTime("2004-07-21"), 1, 10),
                (5, "Man of Arms", 152, Convert.ToDateTime("2003-02-17"), 1, 9),
                (6, "Man of War", 93, Convert.ToDateTime("2017-07-05"), 2, 8),
                (7, "Man of Legs", 33, Convert.ToDateTime("2018-11-11"), 1, 9),
                (8, "Mof", 55, Convert.ToDateTime("2015-11-11"), 2, 8) };
            var movieActorArr = new (int, int)[] 
            {   (1,1), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5),
                (2,1), (2,5),
                (3,4),
                (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4),
                (5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5),
                (6,1), (6,2), (6,3),
                (7,2), (7,4), (7,5),
                (8,1), (8,4) };
```

Comment: So you want the name of directors which have directed 3 to 7 actors and have two or more movies over 60 minutes?

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? LINQ To Objects? LINQ To Entity Framework (and what version of EF if so)? Can you post your C# models so it's easier for us to reproduce?

Comment: @Hogan Directors, which directed 2 or more movies over 60 minutes in each of which 3 to 7 actors participated. Now Im thinkig, that my SQL query is also need some changes.

Comment: @42ama yeah your SQL was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came up with solution. 
First of all I changed SQL query (with SO help):

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM (SELECT m.Id, d.Name, COUNT(*) as NumActors
      FROM Director d 
           JOIN Movie m
           ON d.Id = m.DirectorId 
           JOIN MovieActor ma
           ON m.Id = ma.MovieId
      WHERE m.ReleaseDate <= '2005-12-31' AND
            m.Rating >= 9 AND
            m.DurationMinutes >= 60
      GROUP BY d.Name, m.Id
      HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 3 AND 7
     ) m 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

And then in the image modyfied linq query.

```cs
var query4 = (from x in 
                 (from d in directors
                     join m in movies2 
                         on d.Id equals m.DirectorId
                     join ma in movieActors 
                         on m.Id equals ma.MovieId
                     where m.ReleaseDate <= Convert.ToDateTime("2005-12-31")
                     where m.Rating >= 9
                     where m.DurationMinutes >= 60
                     group d by new { d.Name, m.Id } into res
                         where res.Count() >= 3
                         where res.Count() <= 7
                         select res)
                 group x by x.Key.Name into fin
                     where fin.Count() >= 2
                     select fin)
                 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get directors name, which directed 2 or more movies over 60 minutes in each of which 3 to 7 actors participated (as you stated in your comment), then try this:

```
// use group join to get movies with actors
var moviesWithActors = 
    from m in movies.Where(x => x.ReleaseDate <= new DateTime(2015, 12, 31) && x.Rating >= 9)
    join ma in movieActor on m.MovieId equals ma.MovieId into groupJoin
    let actorsInEachMovieCount = groupJoin.Count()
    where actorsInEachMovieCount > 2 && actorsInEachMovieCount < 8
    select new 
    {
        MovieId = m.MovieId,
    };

// the rest of query
var query = 
    from d in directors
    join m in movies on d.Id equals m.DirectorId
    join ma in moviesWithActors on m.MovieId equals ma.MovieId  // use moviesWithActors from the first query
    group new { 
        Director = d.Name, 
        Movie = m
    } by d.Id into gr
    let moviesDurationOver60MinCount = gr.Select(x => x.Movie).Distinct().Count(x => x.DurationMinutes >= 60)
    where moviesDurationOver60MinCount >= 2     
    select new { DirectorName = gr.First().Director };
```

Also, the same can be achieved the following way:

```
// use group join to get movies with duration > 60 min
var filteredMovies = 
    from d in directors
    join m in movies.Where(x => x.DurationMinutes >= 60 && x.ReleaseDate <= new DateTime(2015, 12, 31) && x.Rating >= 9)
    on  d.Id equals m.DirectorId into groupMovies
    let moviesCountForEachDirector = groupMovies.Count()
    where moviesCountForEachDirector > 1
    select groupMovies;

// use group join to get movies with actors from 3 to 7
var moviesWithActors = 
    from m in filteredMovies.SelectMany(x => x)
    join ma in movieActor on m.MovieId equals ma.MovieId into groupJoin
    let actorsInEachMovieCount = groupJoin.Count()
    where actorsInEachMovieCount > 2 && actorsInEachMovieCount < 8
    select new 
    {
        MovieId = m.MovieId,
    };

// the rest of query
var query = 
    from d in directors
    join m in movies on d.Id equals m.DirectorId
    join ma in moviesWithActors on m.MovieId equals ma.MovieId
    group d by d.Id into gr 
    select new { DirectorName = gr.First().Name };
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It always baffles me, that if people have a requirement that they need to solve using LINQ, they don't give us the requirement, but first translate the requirement into SQL and give us the SQL instead of the requirement.

It seems to me that you want a LINQ statement that returns the following:

> Give me all names of directors that have directed movies on or before a certain `date`, with a rating higher or equal than a certain rating number, for at least 2 movies that were longer at least one hour, with at least 3 and at utmost 7 actors

If you have one-to-many or many-to-many relationships between tables, and you want "Items with their many sub-items" like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, Orders with their OrderLines, you should think of using [Enumerable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.8)

If on the other hand, you want the sub-item with the one item that it belongs to, like the Student with the one and only School that he attend, or the Order with the one and only Customer that placed this Order, use [Enumerable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8)

In this case, we want Directors with his Movies, so we'll use GroupJoin.

```
TimeSpan oneHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
var result = directors.GroupJoin(movies,
    director => director.Id,              // from each director take the Id
    movie => movie.DirectorId             // from each movie take the DirectorId

    // result selector: take every director with all his movies to make one new:
    (director, moviesOfThisDirector) => new
    {
        // from the director we only need his name
        Name = director.Name

        // From each of his movies we need the ReleaseDate, the Rating and the number of actors
        Movies = moviesOfThisDirector.Select(movie => new
        {
            ReleaseDate = movie.ReleaseDate,
            Rating = movie.Rating,
            Duration = movie.Duration,

            NumberOfActors = movie.GroupJoin(actors,
                movie => movie.Id,
                actor => actor.MovieId,

                // ResultSelector: only count all Actors in this movie
                (movie, actorsInThisMovie) => actorInThisMovie.Count(),
        })
        // well, we don't want all movies,
        // we only want movies before a date with a high rating and a certain duration
        .Where(movie => movie.ReleaseDate <= myDate
                     && movie.Rating >= myRating
                     && movie.Duration >= oneHour),
    })
    // we don't want all Directors, we only want those that have at least one such a movie
    .Where(directory => directory.Movies.Any();
```

**Possible improvements**

You want to group directors by name. Are you sure that there are no directors with the same name? It will be faster to join directors by Id, besides you'll know this Id is unique.

You seem to have designed a one-to-many relation between Movies and Actors: every Movie has zero or more Actors, every Actor plays in exactly one Movie. Normally every movie has zero or more actors, and every actor plays in zero or more movies: a many-to-many relationship, which needs a junction table. Consider whether you really want a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: There is a comma missing after `move.DirectorId` and an extra one in two places.  Your code sample would not compile.